# Keeping the Google Maps state in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to build an app with navigation to multiple different screens (using Bottom Navigation).
One of the screens, the `startDestination`, is a Google Maps view, looking at [Official compose example: Crane](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Crane) to get it to work, and it does.

However, when navigating to another screen, and back, the `MapView` gets recomposed and is slowly loading back in. We start back at the initial camera position, zoom level, and so on. There probably is a way to `remember` and re-apply those attributes, but I am more interested in keeping the complete state of the Google Maps view intact. (Looking at the current Google Maps app, for Android, it does exactly what I'm looking for, eventhough they aren't using Jetpack Compose)

Is there a way to achieve this?

I already `remember` the `MapView`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun rememberMapViewWithLifecycle(): MapView {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context).apply {
            id = R.id.map
        }
    }

    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    DisposableEffect(lifecycle, mapView) {
        // Make MapView follow the current lifecycle
        val lifecycleObserver = getMapLifecycleObserver(mapView)
        lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        }
    }

    return mapView
}

private fun getMapLifecycleObserver(mapView: MapView): LifecycleEventObserver =
    LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> mapView.onCreate(Bundle())
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> mapView.onStart()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> mapView.onResume()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> mapView.onPause()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> mapView.onDestroy()
            else -> throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    }
```

To give more context, the `MapView` is in the top of this screen

```kotlin
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun MapsScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: EventViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    ...
    val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifecycle()
    MapsScreenView(modifier, uiState, mapView)
}
```

A completely different approach I tried, is through a `BackdropScaffold` (*in* a `Scaffold` because I want the `BottomBar`..) where `backLayerContent` is the `MapsScreen()` and the `frontLayerContent` are the other screens, the "front" is configured so it will cover the entire screen when active. It feels really ugly and horrible, but it kinda works..

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        SmallTopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "Test") },
        )
    },
    bottomBar = {
        BottomBar(navController) { screen ->
            showMaps = screen == Screen.MainMaps
            coroutineScope.launch {
                if (showMaps) scaffoldState.reveal() else scaffoldState.conceal()
            }
        }
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            BackdropScaffold(
                scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                appBar = { },
                frontLayerContent = {
                    EventsScreen()
                },
                backLayerContent = {
                    MapsScreen()
                },
                peekHeight = if (showMaps) 300.dp else 0.dp,
                headerHeight = if (showMaps) BackdropScaffoldDefaults.HeaderHeight else 0.dp,
                gesturesEnabled = showMaps
            )
        }
    }
)
```

Did anyone have this same problem and found an actual solution? (We really need Jetpack Compose support for this I guess, intead of the `AndroidView` approach)

Comment: Perhaps using rememberSaveable (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#restore-ui-state) would do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I think that applies to classes that can be parcelizable or can be saved using a Saver, and I'm not sure how to apply that for `MapView`

Answer (score 3):

Google just publish a library to handle the MapView state [Android-Maps-Compose](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose)

```
val cameraPositionState: CameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState()
GoogleMap(cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState)
Button(onClick = { cameraPositionState.move(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn()) }) { 
 Text(text = "Zoom In") 
}
```

Comment: Awesome, gonna check that out ASAP! Reporting back whether that helped.

Comment: Is this Google maps only ? How would you achieve this with Mailbox ?